# Error opening a Word doc file downloaded from a SQL SERVER Image field

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, varbinary

I have a SQL SERVER 2017 database in which there is a table containing records with a field of type Image. There are Word doc files in this field. When I try to download the contents of these fields to generate real doc files, the file is generated without errors, but when I go to open it with Microsoft Word it tells me that the file is unreadable. Where am I wrong?

```
Sub Main(args As String())
        Dim connectionString As String = GetConnectionString()
        Dim filePath As String = GetDirectoryRadiceLocale() + "\verbali\" + args(0) + ".doc"

        Dim WordContents As Byte()
        Dim selectStmt As String = "SELECT verbale FROM testata_assemblea WHERE id_assemblea = @id"

        Using connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)

            Using cmdSelect As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(selectStmt, connection)
                cmdSelect.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(args(0))
                connection.Open()
                WordContents = CType(cmdSelect.ExecuteScalar(), Byte())
                connection.Close()
            End Using
        End Using

        File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, WordContents)
    End Sub
```

I have tried several solutions without success. I also downloaded a little program called SQL Image View to check if the doc files could actually be seen or if there was some archiving problem. The little program SQL Image View shows me correctly the Word files
[This is what I see when I open the downloaded file with Word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3h3UP.png)

Comment: An Image Viewer is showing Word documents? Change the Field's type to `VARBINARY(MAX)`, store a byte array of the files' content (if you actually need to store these files *inside* the db) and possibly show how you're doing this

Comment: I have already tried unsuccessfully to change the field type to varbinary(MAX).
Sql Image View is a tool that allows you to extrapolate the content of the Image type field, content that can be a word, excel, pdf file....then obviously you need to have the program to open the file type.
The data in the table is entered by users with Ole Object technology through a front-end made with access 2003 with an adp type file. The image I have attached is what I see by opening the file downloaded from the above procedure and then opened with Word

Comment: So, you're storing an OLE object (a *Package*), created in Access. You're going to have some extra bytes at the beginning of the actual data bytes (IIRC, possibly also at the end) -- If the Word document is stored as a file (from the File System), since it's actually a pkzip archive, you could look for the `50 4B 03 04` sequence to identify the beginning of the file -- Or wait for someone that remembers how to read a MS Access OLE package (assuming this is the storage method)

Comment: If they're `Word.Document.8` they'll be (pre-.docx) .doc files and won't have a zip header, most likely they'll be starting with the `D0 CF 11 E0` magic numbers.